# Conservation of painting on cardboard

Tags: painting, preservation, acrylic-paint, cardboard

Last week I bought a painting on cardboard. The problem is that some divisions of my home have a LOT of humidity. This artwork is intended for my future home, so I need to store it for some months.

The painting is fully wrapped in film paper, it was sent this way by the author. Should I remove the film paper, or should I keep it wrapped? My question is about mould and paper deformation.

Comment: If not all of your home has the humidity problem, store it in one of the drier areas, and leave the film on. You could even enclose it in a large plastic bag with a "closet dehumidifier" inside. However, if humidity is so high that you worry about cardboard going soft and moldy, the painting should not be at the top of your list for what you're worried about. Plenty of other surfaces can get a mold bloom, and that can have serious health risks. You might want to consider asking a question about options for controlling the humidity on the [Home Improvement](https://diy.stackexchange.com) site.

Comment: In addition to that avoid storing the painting in a place with changing temperatures, like an unheated attic or basement. Especially avoid leaning the painting against outside walls that aren't insulated. I've seen several paintings warp because of the changing temperatures, even ones hanging on the outside walls of heated rooms.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with film paper is that it impedes the breathability of the materials. If your house is a lot more humid than the author's house, unpacking the painting will result in the cardboard absorbing a lot of water (and contaminants). However, whatever contaminants *currently* invest the cardboard will prosper in their hermetically sealed vivarium, and affect the cardboard - as well as the paint.

If the work is made with acrylics, it probably has had enough time to dry sufficiently, and can suffer low breathability for a while. But if it's oil paint, you really don't want to keep the artwork sealed in film, as it will impede the drying process and likely cause long-term problems.

**I'd suggest letting a friend, family member, neighbour, colleague, or acquaintance (I *think* those are all the options :-) ), store it in a space** where - as *Elmy* suggests in the comments - the atmosphere is stable.

You'll want low humidity, a temperature between ca. 15° and 25° Celsius (59° and 77° Fahrenheit), low light or darkness, no dust, and to keep it away from doors, windows, or other potential sources of shifts in these conditions, and out of reach of most things: you don't want people storing things on top of it, or against it, or for it to keep getting moved.

If that's really not an option, storing it in the most environmentally stable room of your house is the best choice, preferably - as *fixer1234* suggests - along with a dehumidifier.

But I would advise you to take the work out of the film in that case and wrap it - loosely! - in bubble wrap: this both allows for breathing and will protect the work, especially the edges. Then place it in another container, like a drawer, where it will stay out of the light and have an extra layer of isolation, so that any changes in temperature and humidity will be minimized.